# Creating a file where content is in a batch code

Tags: file, for-loop, batch-file, while-loop, creation

I want to create a another file output from the batch file that I am running, meaning the raw content is inside it. Inside this batch file it would do a while or for loop until it has found the "end" or any unique word that I add at the end of the content.

I don't want to simply copy the file(which has important content) as this will expose information. Then run it by calling the file via batch.

```
code:
-start of batch
-check if the file a.txt exist del a.txt
-starts to create the a.txt file

>start of content:
>"the quick brown fox jump over the lazy dog"
>lynx: unique word
>end of content

-writes the content to a.txt using for loop or while until it finds the unique word
-runs the a.txt file
-deletes the a.txt file
-exit
```

Hope someone can help. Thank you!
Or if someone can suggest a better way to do it. I would appreciate it

Comment: Why do you need to create the new batch file? Why not simply call the code as a function within your existing batch file?

Answer (score 0):

The line with the for command itself will need quotes.

For loops work fine until they hit a line that contains quote marks then everything turns to custard...

You can't get there form here.

Maybe try vbscript instead?

Comment: @user1701414 - Actually, quotes aren't that big of a deal, especially if they are consistent. What will turn everything sideways is redirection and pipeing characters like <>|<<. Even if you know they are there they can be very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if exist a.txt del a.txt

copy nul a.txt > nul                      & :: Not needed, but in your specs

set line[1]=This is what you asked for.
set line[2]=Not really the best method.
set line[3]=But it will work.
set line[4]=
set line[5]=linux
set line[6]=[end]

for /l %%i in (1,1,1000) do (
  if     "!line[%%i]!"=="linux" goto :end
  if     "!line[%%i]!"=="[end]" goto :end
  if     "!line[%%i]!"=="" echo.>>a.txt
  if NOT "!line[%%i]!"=="" echo !line[%%i]!>>a.txt
)

:end
:: Broken Out Of Loop

ren a.txt a.bat
call a.bat
del a.bat
```

Using the `line[n]` method is rather wasteful of memory, I would reccomend moving the data from one file to another.